# Moving average after groupby a column

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, rolling-computation

```
   CargoTons   DateOrigin  DateDestination Origin  Destination
0   72875.0 2020-01-01  2020-01-08  Snohvit Dragon
1   77126.0 2020-01-01  2020-01-16  Cameron (Liqu.) Grain
2   0       2020-01-02          
3   67500.0 2020-01-03  2020-01-18  Sabine Pass South Hook
4   93843.0 2020-01-04  2020-01-23  Ras Laffan  South Hook
5   76239.0 2020-01-05  2020-01-14  Yamal       Grain
6   71749.0 2020-01-05  2020-01-23  Sabine Pass Dragon
7   75353.0 2020-01-06  2020-01-22  Sabine Pass South Hook
8   71749.0 2020-01-07  2020-01-21  Sabine Pass South Hook
9   0       2020-01-08          
10  96925.0 2020-01-09  2020-01-25  Ras Laffan  South Hook
11  65013.0 2020-01-10  2020-01-22  Snohvit     Grain
12  76505.0 2020-01-10  2020-01-19  Yamal       Dragon
13  0       2020-01-11          
14  0       2020-01-12          
15  0       2020-01-13          
16  0       2020-01-14          
17  0       2020-01-15
```

Above is a snapshot of the data available.

I would like to have a moving average column which give the MA based on dates and not rows-i.e the days where I have multiple entries for the same date should just have one value as the MA.

I want the MA to be calculated on the first grouping by Origin and then over the dates.

Below is the script for the missing dates in each Origin group-

```
start = pd.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = pd.datetime(2020,1,31)  
index = pd.date_range(start, end)
mockdata = pd.DataFrame()
mockdata['DateOrigin'] = index
```

Comment: You might be able to use rolling with transform.

Comment: Could you paste a sample solution please- the MA can be say 2 dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
```

Data example:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
   CargoTons DateOrigin Origin
 0 72875.0 2020-01-01 Snohvit
 1 77126.0 2020-01-01 Cameron
 2 0 2020-01-02          
 3 67500.0 2020-01-03 SabinePass
 4 93843.0 2020-01-04 RasLaffan
 5 76239.0 2020-01-05 Yamal
 6 71749.0 2020-01-05 SabinePass
 7 75353.0 2020-01-06 SabinePass
 8 71749.0 2020-01-07 SabinePass
 9 0 2020-01-08          
 10 96925.0 2020-01-09 RasLaffan
 11 65013.0 2020-01-10 Snohvit
 12 76505.0 2020-01-10 Yamal
 13 0 2020-01-11          
 14 0 2020-01-12          
 15 0 2020-01-13          
 16 0 2020-01-14          
 17 0 2020-01-15
 """), sep="\s", engine="python")
```

You could use `groupby` on Origin and DateOrigin, to first compute the mean for different values at the same dates.

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Origin', 'DateOrigin']).aggregate('CargoTons').mean()).reset_index()
```

Then use `rolling`, for example mean on a window of 2. Take `Origin` as groupby.

```
ndf.groupby(['Origin']).rolling(2).mean()
```

Which gives:

```
               CargoTons
Origin                  
Cameron    0         NaN
RasLaffan  1         NaN
           2     95384.0
SabinePass 3         NaN
           4     69624.5
           5     73551.0
           6     73551.0
Snohvit    7         NaN
           8     68944.0
Yamal      9         NaN
           10    76372.0
```

**Verification**

As you see, in each category of `Origin` it is starting with NAN, which is expected because of the rolling window. The output of for ex. Snohvit 68944.0 is the average of its input, (72875+65013)/2.

Comment: This doesn't do it when we include the Origin/Destination columns

Comment: @Ameya Vikram: Could you check with the added line of code?

Comment: @Ruthger: I think you mean the command "mean()" instead of "sum()"

Comment: @kenny_123: You are right as the OP uses the term moving average and not moving window ;-).

Comment: No it doesn't give the rolling average when I want to group it by Origin/Destination-
merge5=merge2.groupby(['DateOrigin','Origin']).aggregate('CargoTons').mean().rolling(3).mean()

a1=pd.merge(merge2,
         merge5,
         on='DateOrigin',
         how='left')

This is giving an aggregated value for each date rather than giving the MA value for each individual Origin point

Comment: @Ameya Vikram: I have edited the answer, let me know if this gives what you need.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart kind of the thing is the calculation needs to be carried out individually on each origin point i.e Sabine Pass/Yamal all from scratch then it will solve the problem

Comment: @AmeyaVikram: good point, in the previous solution the rolling values in one category of Origin were influenced by the previous values of a different category, which is indeed not correct. Please check the current solution which should deal with this issue.